# Cannot seem to retrieve image Files from FormData values in my Lumen PHP app

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, image, lumen

I have the following request to send image files to my PHP endpoint:

```
        const formData  = new FormData();

        Object.keys(this.state.productData).forEach((key) => {
            if (key === "files") {
                formData.append(key, this.state.productData[key]);
            }
        });

        for (let value of formData.values()) {
            console.log(value);
        }

        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/products/submit`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        })
```

Now as proof the value i get from the console.log is this:

> [object File]

In my PHP endpoint I do the following:

```
return response([$request->get('files')]);
```

This however results in:

> ["[object File]"]

Also

```
response([$request->hasFile('files'), $request->get('files')]);
```

returns: [true, null]

Any help to get my image files from my react app to php endpoint would be highly appreciated.

My Image files are stored into the stated as the "files" values after i upload them using: FileReader() in js:

```
handleImageChange = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        let files = Array.from(e.target.files);

        files.forEach((file, i) => {
                let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = () => {
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    files: [...prevState.files, file],
                    imagesPreviewUrls: [...prevState.imagesPreviewUrls, reader.result]
                }));
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    };
```

Comment: According to documentation, it’s $request->file(), not ->get() (https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/requests#files)

Comment: Yes, I tried that too and i just get null. response([$request->hasFile('files'), $request->get('files')]); returns [true, null]

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve image files from FormData values in your Lumen PHP application, you need to do the following:

```
return response([$request->file('files')]);
```